# Java HttpClient - second call always fails

Tags: java, spring-boot, http, httpclient

I am using `java.net.http.HttpClient` in my Java Spring Boot app and I noticed this weird behaviour.

When my code call HTTP request to 3rd party API, next request to different 3rd party API returns always as bad request (400). When I execute this request first, it works just fine.

When I restart the app, first API call is always successful, but second one is always bad and so I have to call it again after some timeout and then it work.

So I was thinking, if there is any form of "cache" that remember previous settings or whatever from previous request, because second request to different API is always bad. When I inspected HttpRequest in debugger, it seems okay to me and there was nothing really different from the one that worked.

Here is my bean config

```
@Configuration
public class HttpClientBean {

    @Bean
    public HttpClient httpClient() {
        return HttpClient.newHttpClient();
    }
}
```

HttpRequest builder

```
    public static HttpRequest buildGetRequest(final String url) {
        return HttpRequest.newBuilder()
                .uri(URI.create(url))
                .GET()
                .build();
    }

    public static HttpRequest buildPostRequest(final String url, final String body) {
        return HttpRequest.newBuilder()
                .version(HttpClient.Version.HTTP_1_1)
                .uri(URI.create(url))
                .setHeader(CONTENT_TYPE, APPLICATION_JSON)
                .POST(HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.ofString(body))
                .build();
    }
```

and here is HttpService

```
@Service
public class HttpServiceImpl implements HttpService {

    private final HttpClient httpClient;

    @Autowired
    public HttpServiceImpl(final HttpClient httpClient) {
        this.httpClient = httpClient;
    }

    @Override
    public HttpResponse<String> sendGetRequestWithParams(final String url, final String params) throws Exception {
        final HttpRequest request = buildGetRequest(url, params);
        return httpClient.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());
    }

    @Override
    public HttpResponse<String> sendGetRequestWithoutParams(final String url) throws Exception {
        final HttpRequest request = buildGetRequest(url);
        return httpClient.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());
    }

    @Override
    public HttpResponse<String> sendPostRequestWithBody(final String url, final String body) throws Exception {
        final HttpRequest request = buildPostRequest(url, body);
        return httpClient.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());
    }
}
```

Thank you for your advices.

Comment: Examine the traffic using Wireshark or tcpdump to see what's actually being sent and received.

Comment: that should absolutely not happen, as the doc states : "Once built, an HttpClient is immutable, and can be used to send multiple requests". And the fact that without code changes, after some timeout, it works - indicates a problem in the 3-rd party service, not the client.

Comment: But the error only appears when I call it as a second request, which is really weird, because obviously something has changed, because when I call it as a first request, it just work..

Comment: unless you annotate my name with `@` when posting a comment - I have no idea you added one. And then, unless you find a way for us to re-produce, we can't help. To answer your question directly: no, there is no cache in the http client.

Comment: @Eugene I don't think there is a way to reproduce this without having my code, so I am just asking, if someone had same issue or if someone experienced such behaviour. Do you think that switching to different HttpClient could help me?

Comment: we have used http client since it was is incubator mode, that us years already. first time I see or hear about something like this. I would still look into that 3-rd party API.

Comment: Try to switch on request/response headers logging:
`-Djdk.httpclient.HttpClient.log="errors,requests,headers"` - it may reveal what is going on.

Comment: @PetrJelínek: I have found a related error in our code, though I haven't determined the root cause yet. If I construct a java.net.HttpClient and use it, constructing a different HttpClient and trying to use that one always fails. I'm caching HTTPS context, and it looks like that has to be constructed before the first HttpClient construction of any kind--even one that doesn't use that context. I'll continue to drill, but just commenting out that first HTTP client construction solved my subsequent call problems.